# I can't read the values in xml file with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file with the structure below, and I can't read the "Var_" values ​​before the text, Var_A ecc...
What am I doing wrong?

```
<VarList>
<VarProject Var_A="1" Var_B="1" Var_C="" Var_D="" VarE="">text_text_text</VarProject>
</VarList>
```

And this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ReadXMLfromFile
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("file.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. What is your output and what output do you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here on Stack Overflow and I don't speak English very well.
I'm a newbie on C# and XML files and I didn't know they were called attributes.
Thanks a lot for the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you missed to read the attributes.
You can do it the way it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417020/2032864):

```
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("file.xml");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        reader.NodeType.Dump();
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                  while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) {
                    Console.WriteLine(" {0}={1}", reader.Name, reader.Value);
                  } 
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading only the Node Element parts and not the childNodes
To read child Nodes you can use this code

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"youfilePath");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);
        foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            // node stuff...
            if (item.Attributes != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute att in item.Attributes)
                {
                    // attribute stuff
                }
            }
        }
```

So to do your While Like This

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {


            switch (reader.NodeType)
            { 
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    Console.Write(" < " + reader.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(">");
                    if (reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(" {0}={1}", reader.Name, reader.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(">");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And the result should be :

[image]

Comment: Your initial description is confusing given that child *elements* (which are also nodes) are read. It would be clearer if you'd just say that the OP isn't using the attributes in the reader. It's unclear what the first piece of code is meant for, given that the OP isn't using XmlDocument. (And if you just want to demonstrate that attributes exist, I'd use XDocument as a cleaner, more modern API.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here on Stack Overflow and I don't speak English very well.
I'm a newbie on C# and XML files and I didn't know they were called attributes.
I used an example taken from the Microsoft site and I could not understand why all the data were not displayed.
Thanks a lot for the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [LINQ XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8)

```
 XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

            foreach(XElement element in xml.Descendants())
            {
                // in this example there is only one xElement but that element contains all of our attributes
                // we could also display the element value here (example: text_text_text)
                IEnumerable<XAttribute> attributes = element.Attributes();

                foreach(XAttribute attribute in attributes)
                {
                    // display the attribute name (example: "var_A")
                    Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name);
                    // display the attribute value (example: "1")
                    Console.WriteLine(attribute.Value);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I would or You should !? ;)